# How do you serve a page as html while prompting with a download dialog

Tags: php, jquery

I have a link which launches a new html page in a new tab with simple jquery, like `_target=blank`, no issue.

Expected:

- Page opened in a new tab, and should be kept opened, and a Save as dialog prompted

Current unexpected behavior:

- Page is opened in a new tab, and then closed with a Save dialog prompted

Shortly, I want to keep the page open, while prompting a Save as dialog.

Using `Content-Disposition` attachment seems to have no chance to keep the page open.
I didn't do any `exit();` either, but the page is never showed, except for the dialog.

Thanks

Comment: In your jQuery code, is "return false" in any of the functions that are being used in this process?

Comment: The jquery does nothing except: window.open(url, 'external'); I am expecting more server side thing. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try pulling your page initially as a normal page, and use a meta refresh to redirect to the same url with a parameter telling your PHP to serve the page again as a download.

Example:

```
<?php
$isDownload = isset( $_GET['download'] );
if( $isDownload ) {
    header( 'Content-disposition: attachment' );
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php if( !$isDownload ) { ?>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>?download" />
        <?php } ?>
...
```

Comment: Yes, sounds good, but no idea yet with how to bring it into my codes :)

Comment: Thanks that param things is a winding road in my CMS :)

Comment: Looks like you might have already figured it out, but I added an example.

Comment: Yes thanks, my CMS is a bit layered unless you accept hardcoded things happily, and not easy to get this info: 'query' => array('download' => NULL),

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is a good answer or not.. but perhaps.. open the page that displays the save as dialog box & try some document.location.href = "abspathtofile"; in js.. though i'm not sure if this is what you're looking for..

Answer (score 1):

Insert a meta refresh tag into the page that you are currently serving in the popup. This meta refresh should point to the file you want to be downloaded:

```
popup.php:

<head>
    ...
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL='http://www.example.com/downloads/file.ext'" />    
    ...
</head>
```

This will show popup.php in the new window, and after 10 seconds a save dialog will show prompting the user to download the file `file.ext`

Answer (score 0):

send refresh headers

> header("Refresh: 5; url=http://www.example.com?download=1");

instead of the need to modify your template to add meta tags